# Axios call on an EC2 encounter timeout way shorter than realtime

Tags: amazon-ec2, axios, timeout

I have an Express application running on an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2) that utilizes Axios for calling external APIs. The API call is configured with a timeout threshold of 15 seconds (15000 ms). However, when attempting to connect to an unresponsive API, Axios throws a timeout error in just 5 seconds, which is 10 seconds faster than the specified 15-second setting. Interestingly, despite the shorter duration, the error message correctly reflects the intended timeout duration. This identical code worked seamlessly on AWS Lambda and elsewhere, consistently ensuring synchronization between the error message and the timeEnd() output. Has anyone else encountered a similar behavior?

```js
try {
  console.time()
  const response = await axios.get('https://httpbin.org/delay/20', { timeout: 15000 });
  console.log('Response:', response.data);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Error:', err.message);
} finally {
  console.timeEnd();
}
```

Result:

```
Error: timeout of 15000ms exceeded
default: 5.07s
```